# httpWebRequest Referer exception with unicode url

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-referer

I have some code use httpWebRequest to post data, but when i use unicode text in Referer it always show exception: "Specified value has invalid Control characters."

```
            CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate";
            httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = (DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate);
            httpWebRequest.Timeout = this.Timeout;
            httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            httpWebRequest.Method = method;
            httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = this.KeepAlive;
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = this.ContentType;
            httpWebRequest.Accept = this.Accept;
            httpWebRequest.UserAgent = this.UserAgent;
            httpWebRequest.Referer = this.Referer;
            httpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            httpWebRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
            httpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
            httpWebRequest.Credentials =  CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            httpWebRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
```

The url is: `somewhere.com/index?1yyezksvrgzkelork□=rgu{z5iihy5zvreiihy&1iutlomLork=gjsot5otjk~`
Referer: `somewhere.com/index?1yyezksvrgzkelork□=rgu{z5iihy5zvreiihy&1iutlomLork=gjsot5otjk~`
If use only url it's running normally.

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding your referer with HttpUtility.UrlEncode(...)